# How do I align text on the right side in my document?

Tags: text

I would like to align the following text on the right side in my document:

```
                                                                      Examiner: 
                                                                      Professor Name....

                                                                      Submitted by: 
                                                                      Student Name.....
```

I tried to use \flushright and latex returns:

```
                                                                                  Examiner: 
                                                                      Professor Name.......

                                                                              Submitted by: 
                                                                      Student Name.........
```

Hence, I would like to implement the first example. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try using again `\flushright`, but additionally putting the whole text in a `\begin{tabular}{l} … \end{tabular}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
  \begin{minipage}{4cm}
    Examiner:

    Professor Name\dots

    \bigskip
    Submitted by:
    
    Student Name\dots
  \end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly!!

Comment: I would have gone with `\hspace*(\fill}` for a single minipage.